# Is there open source software which is to Process Monitor what ProcessHacker is to Process Explorer?

Tags: windows, software-rec, process-explorer, sysinternals

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net) is an open source alternative to the [famous Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896653) by Mark Russinovitch.

Is there in the same vein a piece of open source software that can be a serious alternative to [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)?

Comment: at the moment I doubt it. Before process monitor , the closest thing was regmon and filemon, which were also sysinternals. and other than that people use uninstallers to monitor before and after a process runs.  hope you find things though

Comment: I'm curious why you're looking for an open source alternative to Process Explorer? It is, after all, totally free and I have had nothing but a good experience when using it.

Comment: @cmorse: Several reasons: · I would like to see the code for curiosity · The license of Process Explorer is quite restrictive for the company I work for (no redistributing it for example).

Comment: @cmorse if you want to pre-empt the stallman fanatics taking issue of your use of the term free, or even acknowledge stallman in the topic of open source / libre software  then a better phrase to use would be to say it "totally no cost". process explorer isn't libre but it is no cost.

Comment: @barlop Yeah, good point. I might just start using "gratis" from now on to avoid confusion.

Comment: I suppose this depends on what you might want Process Monitor for.  At the time of this writing, the Process Hacker downloads page does refer to https://systeminformer.sourceforge.io which seems to be similar software that can look at processes, and report on what files get used, and some other activity, although I didn't see much of anything about registry access.  (So as much as Process Explorer can be said to perform tasks like what Filemon can do, but even more, System Informer may fulfill that role.  But as much as Process Explorer performs Regmon's tasks but even more, not so much.)

Answer (score 2):

[Yet Another Process Monitor](http://yaprocmon.sourceforge.net/) is a very good open source alternative.

If you are particularly interested in taking a look at the code base, let me tell you, the code is a little messy at the moment. But its simple enough to understand whats going on under the hood.

The source code is available at [sourceforge](http://yaprocmon.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/yaprocmon/)

Comment: I'm not seeing where YAPM does the same thing that Process Monitor does.  It looks more like an alternative to Process Explorer instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [Process History](http://processhistory.sourceforge.net/), to record process starting and stopping as Process monitor does. Which is open source based on WTL, SQLite and Boost, Process Hacker.